# can we get which peer we have accessed in tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, peer

I was working on a project using react and tailwindCSS where i want to show the name of the image on the center of the screen when we hover the image. I thought i can use peer concept of tailwindCSS.i can access the name now but i need to write the same code for every element so is thier any way can i know which peer(image) i have hovered so that i can use that particular peer(image) name so that i can use it in a code efficient way

Is their any way that we can get which peer or sibling is being hovered using tailwind CSS??
or any other possible way i can get that??or i need to write it for every image??